# linq to sql query using methods

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Why does this work ?

```
var x = from p in db.People let oCount = p.Orders.Count select p;
```

And not this ?

```
var x = from p in db.People let oCount = Count(p) select p;

private int Count(DataContext.Order o)
{
  return o.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ to SQL "understands" `p.Orders.Count`, but it can't look inside your method to work out what it means - it could be doing anything as far as LINQ to SQL is concerned.

In your first query, `p.Orders.Count` is all represented in an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) which can be examined programmatically at execution time.

Comment: Thought as much but that means I'm going to be writing one very long and confusing looking query. Many thanks.

Comment: Proper line breaks and indenting will help out a lot.

Comment: As well as separating it out into multiple statements/queries (since the execution is delayed, you can split it out into multiple statements without hitting the database until you need to use the query results).

Comment: This isn't even LINQ to SQL specific - in the first case the compiler produces an expression tree that a LINQ provider can translate. In the second case it produces the Count part as IL which would require runtime reverse-engineering/decompilation before it could try and figure out what was going on and translate it.